# Overriding a virtual member function

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I have the following classes

Entity

```
class Entity {
  public:
    virtual std::ostream& write(std::ostream& os) const {
        os << "Can't output Entity";
        return os;
    }
};
```

And StringEntity

```
class StringEntity : public Entity {
  public:
    std::string data;

    StringEntity(std::string str) {
        data = str;
    }

    std::ostream& write(std::ostream& os) const {
        os << data;
        return os;
    }
};
```

Using these classes like so

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    StringEntity entity = StringEntity("MY STRING ENTITY");
    Entity gen_ent      = (Entity) entity;

    entity.write(std::cout)  << std::endl;
    gen_ent.write(std::cout) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Because the base Entity class' write function is virtual and write is overriden in the derived StringEntity class, I would expect both write statements to print out `MY STRING ENTITY`. Instead, the first one correctly prints `MY STRING ENTITY`, but the second prints `Can't output Entity`.

How do I override a function such that it is completely overriden (ie. not dependent upon how a variable is declared)?

Comment: Other possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18841606/1896169

Comment: The gen_ent is an Entity object.  The write method of an Entity object prints out "Can't output Entity".