# Array of different data types

Tags: c++, arrays, inheritance

I need to store an array of newspapers and booklets
And then in a loop, print out how much paper it takes to print each product, but when I call the price calculation function, the function is called from the main class and not from the child ones, how can I call the function from the child classes in an array with different objects?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class PrintedProduct
{
public:
    string name;
    int pages;
    int paperCost()
    {
        return 1;
    }
    PrintedProduct() {}
    PrintedProduct(string name, int pages)
    {
        this->name = name;
        this->pages = pages;
    }
};

class NewsPaper : public PrintedProduct
{
public:
    int pageSize;
    int quantity;
    int period;
    NewsPaper(string name, int pages, int pageSize, int quantity, int period) : PrintedProduct(name, pages)
    {
        this->pageSize = pageSize;
        this->quantity = quantity;
        this->period = period;
    }
    int paperCost()
    {
        return pages * pageSize * quantity * period;
    }
};

class Booklet : public PrintedProduct
{
public:
    int pageSize;
    int quantity;
    Booklet(string name, int pages, int pageSize, int quantity)
        : PrintedProduct(name, pages)
    {
        this->pageSize = pageSize;
        this->quantity = quantity;
    }
    int paperCost()
    {
        return pages * pageSize * quantity;
    }
};

void print(PrintedProduct a)
{
    cout << a.paperCost() << endl;
};

int main()
{
    // Write C++ code here
    size_t size;
    cout << "Please, enter a size of the array: " << endl;
    cin >> size;
    PrintedProduct *array = new PrintedProduct[size];

    cout
        << "Please, enter "
        << size
        << " Printed products: ";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << "Please enter: 1. Newspaper or 2. Booklet";
        int type;
        cin >> type;
        if (type == 1)
        {
            cout << "Enter name:" << endl;
            string name;
            cin >> name;

            cout << "Enter page count" << endl;
            int pages;
            cin >> pages;

            cout << "Enter page size " << endl;
            int pageSize;
            cin >> pageSize;

            cout << "Enter quantity" << endl;
            int quantity;
            cin >> quantity;

            cout << "Enter period" << endl;
            int period;
            cin >> period;

            array[i] = NewsPaper(name, pages, pageSize, quantity, period);
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Enter name:";
            string name;
            cin >> name;

            cout << "Enter page count";
            int pages;
            cin >> pages;

            cout << "Enter page size";
            int pageSize;
            cin >> pageSize;

            cout << "Enter quantity";
            int quantity;
            cin >> quantity;

            array[i] = Booklet(name, pages, pageSize, quantity);
        }
    }

    for (size_t j = 0; j < size; j++)
    {
        print(array[j]);
    }
    delete[] array;

    std::system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Read up on `virtual` functions in whatever resource you use to learn C++. You will need to change some other things as well, since your array can only hold objects of type `PrintedProduct` - everything else is sliced

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18841606/2932052

Comment: It's not possible in C++ to have polymorphic arrays (or other containers). Use an array (or vector) of `PrintedProduct` **pointers** instead. Also, the `paperCost` member function should be declared `virtual` in the base class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to store an array of newspapers and booklets

This isn't possible. Arrays can only contain objects of one type. In case of `new PrintedProduct[size]` that array contains objects of type `PrintedProduct`. The elements of the array are not instances of classes derived from `PrintedProduct`.

The solution to this is to use indirection. You can create an array of pointers to `PrintedProduct`. Those pointers may point to base sub object of derived classes. In following example, I will be using `std::vector` and `std::unique_ptr` in order to avoid owning bare pointers:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<PrintedProduct>> array(size);
...
array[i] = std::make_unique<NewsPaper>(
    name, pages, pageSize, quantity, period);
```

> how can I call the function from the child classes

You can call a member function from a derived class by overriding a virtual function. Example:

```
class PrintedProduct
{
public:
    virtual int paperCost() = 0;
// ...

class NewsPaper : public PrintedProduct
{
public:
    int paperCost() override
    {
        return pages * pageSize * quantity * period;
    }
// ...
a.paperCost(); // virtual dispatch
```

Comment: "Arrays can only contain objects of one type." What about  using arrays of union or std::variant<>?

Comment: @GabrielStaples Those arrays contain objects of the union type, or objects of the variant type. They are just another form of indirection; albeit one where the storage is in-place.